Win10Pro duplicates pinned AnyDesk icon in Taskbar when clicking it
I have AnyDesk pinned to my Win10Pro pc Taskbar.  I use it frequently.
When I click it, another AnyDesk icon opens in the Taskbar
positioned to the far right of the Taskbar, and not in the System Tray.
My workaround has been to use 7+TaskbarTweaker.  I click 7+TT's "Taskbar Inspector,"
find the 2nd AnyDesk entry, right-click it, click "Change Application ID," find the original AnyDesk icon's Application ID, click it, and doing this merges the two AnyDesk icons into the original AnyDesk icon's position, saving me both Taskbar space and having to remember which Taskbar icon is for what when I want to switch between various apps :-))
However . . . after having gone through all that, when I quit the AnyDesk session, the original AnyDesk icon stays pinned in the Taskbar.  But . . . when I click it to start a new AnyDesk session the above problem repeats with another AnyDesk icon appearing to the far right etc.  This problem remains even after reboots of the pc and I have to go through all the steps again :-((
So, how to not get my AnyDesk icon duplicated when starting every AnyDesk session?
